# Multiply multiple numbers in a cell with odd formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel

Format of Data

[image]

I currently have data in this format. I am wondering how to multiply each number in the cells by a constant (say 2.5) while keeping the format of the original data (i.e in integers). Thank you!

Comment: So in cell 1 the answers would be `62,421*2.5` and `73,221*2.5` and `(51,202)*2.5` with a similar layout as currently exists?  Also can edit your question to include the contents of one of those cells in a code block using ` backticks `

Comment: @ngyuen can u share what u had tried ?

Comment: Generally, when you have an Excel question, starting with "I have multiple information inside one single Excel cell. How should I handle that?", the first approach is to make sure that you don't have such a situation: it is advised to have every piece of information in a separate cell.

Comment: One way to handle multiple data in a single cell; make sure you also have them 'single value per cell' then make those cells be hidden, and merge them for display 'multiple data in single cell' using a formula which picks them up from the single-cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kinda works I guess. It basically disassembles the input, multiplies the values and then reassambles it.

**For the purposes of readability, I renamed C1 to "val" and C2 to "const"**. You can just copy the formula into notepad and replace these with whatever ranges you want. Wrap text must be enabled for the result to display properly!

Another thing to note is that it is not 100% accurate as the amount of spaces in the second row is static (I just put 7 spaces at the beginning of the line). I could make it dynamic if you want. It wouldn't be terribly difficult but the formula would be like twice as long and it's already pretty ridiculous.

[image]

formula for C3:

```
=TEXT(TRIM(LEFT(val,FIND("±",val)-1))*const,"0,000") & " ± " & TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(MID(val,FIND("±",val)+1,FIND("(",val) - FIND("±",val)-1)),CHAR(10),"")*const,"0,000") & CHAR(10) & "       " & "(" & TEXT(TRIM(MID(val,FIND("(",val)+1,LEN(val)-FIND("(",val)-1))*const,"0,000") & ")"
```